# Link's path in modular web design

Tags: php, structure

I'm testing modular web design with PHP and relative paths, as follows:

```
<?php include('top.php'); ?>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
    <!-- Page content -->
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

So it is easy to create the structure of new pages.

In `top.php` I use relative paths to link stylesheets and scripts, as follows:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

But becomes a problem when I want use the same page structure in pages from child directories. `top.php`, `header.php`, and `footer.php` are the same always. In child directories, I use for instance:

```
<?php include('../top.php'); ?>
<?php include('../header.php'); ?>
    <!-- Page content -->
<?php include('../footer.php'); ?>
```

But this is wrong, because relative paths for links (inside the includes). 
How I can write correctly the links inside the includes to use them in any child directory without problems?

I know that I can use absolute paths of the form `http://www.site.com/path/file`, but I don't know the `www.site.com` url yet. How I can make PHP create absolute paths regardless of the domain?

How I can do this correctly?

Sorry for the spelling, I'm not native english speaker.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`__DIR__`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant which points to the location of the file which includes the others. Then use relative(!) paths to the files that you are about to include. Like this:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../include.php');
```